# Angular: display hidden modal

Tags: angular

I have this modal in my html code :

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="centralModalSuccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-success" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And i want to open it in my typescript code like this :

```
this.http.post<any>('/api', test).subscribe(response => {
  if (response) {
    document.getElementById('centralModalSuccess');
  }
});
```

Should i call it with the id in order to display it? since the arria-hidden is true but i don't know how.

Comment: It's better to use angular material dialog. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: I have the same issue and still couldn't solve it

Comment: There are so many angular modals, just pick one

Comment: i can't work with angular material since the project's tools to work with is only bootstrap and angular without any other library

Answer (score 2):

Try to this code:-

**Add model in html:-**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Create app.js file and add this code:-**

```
var popupFunctionObject = (function () {
 return {
  showPopUp: function () {
   $("#myModal").modal({show: true});
  },
  closePopUp: function () {
   $("#myModal").modal({show: false});
  }
 }
})(popupFunctionObject || {})
```

**Add Bootstrap CSS, Jquery, Bootstrap js and app.js file url in angular.json file Like:-**

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./src/app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/jquery.min.js",
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/app.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "mean-app:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "scripts": [
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/jquery.min.js",
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "./src/app/assets/js/main/app.js"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Add In Ts File Like:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

declare var $: any;
declare var popupFunctionObject:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
private sub: any;

 constructor(private router: Router) {
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 closePopUp(){
  popupFunctionObject.closePopUp();
 }

 showPopUp(){
  popupFunctionObject.showPopUp();
 }
}
```

For Example Demo Url:- https://github.com/KapilTrivedi7737/bootstrap-popup-angular

Comment: Should try to avoid using jquery in Angular. There are plenty of  Angular modal components out there that you don't need to introduce jquery.

Comment: i can't work with angular material since the project's tools to work with is only bootstrap and angular without any other library

Comment: as for your solution, i tried it but it doesn't seems to know the javascript code implemented since i get . ==>  popupFunctionObject is not defined

Comment: Hello check this demo:- https://github.com/KapilTrivedi7737/bootstrap-popup-angular